# Spring Boot JNDI Application Setting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, jndi

I am trying to create a test spring boot project that connects to a database using JNDI. Here's my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.name=jdbc/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jdbc/test
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.type=javax.sql.DataSource
spring.datasource.separator=;
```

Here's my config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:jdbc/test");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Here's my `Application.java` file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I run this but I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/example/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/test'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/test'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/test'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.AppConfig.dataSource(AppConfig.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d9e0060.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d9e0060$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c85b73da.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d9e0060.dataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1:**
Here's my `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Boot is designed to simplify all that things.

You should have `datasource url`, `username`, `password` or its `jndi-name` in your properties, not both options together.

Leave only one JNDI name regarding to the datasource in application.properties without prefix.  Hope you configured it on your Tomcat successfully.

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/test
```

Then remove datasource() method from your AppConfig.
Just inject(autowire) the datasource and use it.

Comment: So everything else (username, password, url, etc) should be on the `context.xml` inside the META-INF folder? And what about if i'm running embedded tomcat? Where would I put that information then?

Comment: In this case specify url, username and password in application.properties. Spring Boot will create datasouce itself. You may even omit driver-class-name property, it could be determined by url.

Comment: Hi. Does someone know how can I do to configurate application.properties file when the JNDI AppServer is not localhost.? Something like this: spring.datasource.jndi-name: java://192.151.108.180:7001/jdbc/Procesos... I get the mistake: Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Comment: Hi David. For using the propertie: spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/test is only with embedded servers?, what append when the application is deployed in a external app server like a Jboss or an WebLogic.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk inject the datasource and use it, inject where? My jpa repository?

Comment: @PrabhatGaur As it is only one datasource there is no need to mention it at all. But if want you could inject it in an usual way.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException at NamingManager.java:662